# Creating notifications inside the BroadcastReceiver : Android

Tags: android, notifications

In my application, i have used C2DM. Here, when i receive a C2DM message/notification, i am trying to create a notification using notification manager. I can properly create notifications, but i am unable to increment the number of unread notifications(using Notification.number) when there are many unread notifications. Since i am creating notification object inside onReceive() function, its getting destroyed as soon as the control comes out of onReceive function. So, the statements

```
public class MyC2dmReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver{

private Context context;

@Override
public void onReceive(Context context1, Intent intent) {
this.context = context1;

    if(intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION")) {    
        handleRegistration(context, intent);
} 
    else if (intent.getAction().equals("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE")) {
        handleMessage(context, intent);
}
}

private void handleMessage(Context context, Intent intent)
{
   .....
   .....   
   Notification notification =     
      new Notification(R.drawable.ic_launcher,intent.getStringExtra("payload"),       
               System.currentTimeMillis());     

   notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
   notification.defaults = Notification.DEFAULT_ALL;
   notification.number += 1;  
}
}
```

have been of no use as it is creating a new notification object everytime. I can not make it(notification object) a static object also. If i make it a static object, even after all the unread notifications are viewed, the notification.number does not get reset. This is basically the problem. Could anybody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store your number of unread messages in a database, flat file, shared preference, or other persistent store. Read in that number when creating your new `Notification`.

Comment: yeah i think thats the only way. I used sharedPreferences. Thanks :)